# How do I check in the regex substitution if capture group is equal to something in replace()?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string and want to replace the values in it with regex and provide the substitution basing on the result of the capture group.

I.e., consider this example:

```
var thing = "thing 1";
var result = thing.replace(/\w+ (\d+)/g,"$1");
```

In this case, the result is `1`, because the substitution takes the match of the capture group 1. Now I want to compare the result of the first capture group with `1` and substitute with `the first`, if it's `1`, otherwise with `a`. In pseudocode, like this:

```
var thing = "thing 1";
var result = thing.replace(/\w+ (\d+)/g,"$1" == "1" ? "the first" : "a");
```

How would I go about it?

Note that the code I've provided is just an example (so please don't suggest something like splitting by space and getting the number, or etc), and I want the solution to work with more complex regexes.

Comment: @Tushar Made a small edit: "substitute with `the first`, if it's 1, otherwise with `a`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) callback:

```
thing.replace(/\w+ (\d+)/g, function (completeMatch, firstCapturedGroup) {
    return firstCapturedGroup == "1" ? "the first" : "a";
});
```

```js
var thing = "thing 1";
var result = thing.replace(/\w+ (\d+)/g, function(e, firstCapturedGroup) {
  return firstCapturedGroup == "1" ? "the first" : "a";
});
document.write(result);
```